# Div Container content overflowing at Mobile Size with Simple Grid System

Tags: html, css, grid, grid-system

I am trying to understand a better way to adapt custom logic to the Simple Grid ([Simple Grid System](http://thisisdallas.github.io/Simple-Grid/) when having custom width div's that are greater than the mobile layout. My issue is that my div widths are greater than the mobile layout and overflowing over the grid ruled padding. For instance, I have a 400px width div that on smaller devices is given a left and right white padding of 20px (grid rule), but since it is greater than the handheld size, my div overflows over the right 20px padding. I am trying to understand the best approach to work with the grid. Should I create my own breakpoint to shrink the div width to fit mobile? Should I use a CSS property that overrides the overflow? What is my best approach? I just want to find a golden standard to work with to keep workflow consistent. Thanks.

[image: Example]

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Simple Grid</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="simplegrid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />


    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Grid 2/3 and 1/3-->
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="col-1-1">
                <div id="test">
                    <h1>This is a test.</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Grid 1/2 -->

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
    background-color: green;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#test h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Simple Grid:

```
/*
  Simple Grid
  Learn More - http://dallasbass.com/simple-grid-a-lightweight-responsive-css-grid/
  Project Page - http://thisisdallas.github.com/Simple-Grid/
  Author - Dallas Bass
  Site - dallasbass.com
*/

*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
}

[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px; /* column-space */
}

.grid {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    min-width: 755px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grid:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.grid-pad {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px; /* grid-space to left */
    padding-right: 0px; /* grid-space to right: (grid-space-left - column-space) e.g. 20px-20px=0 */
}

.push-right {
    float: right;
}

/* Content Columns */

.col-1-1 {
    width: 100%;
}
.col-2-3, .col-8-12 {
    width: 66.66%;
}

.col-1-2, .col-6-12 {
    width: 50%;
}

.col-1-3, .col-4-12 {
    width: 33.33%;
}

.col-1-4, .col-3-12 {
    width: 25%;
}

.col-1-5 {
    width: 20%;
}

.col-1-6, .col-2-12 {
    width: 16.667%;
}

.col-1-7 {
    width: 14.28%;
}

.col-1-8 {
    width: 12.5%;
}

.col-1-9 {
    width: 11.1%;
}

.col-1-10 {
    width: 10%;
}

.col-1-11 {
    width: 9.09%;
}

.col-1-12 {
    width: 8.33%
}

/* Layout Columns */

.col-11-12 {
    width: 91.66%
}

.col-10-12 {
    width: 83.333%;
}

.col-9-12 {
    width: 75%;
}

.col-5-12 {
    width: 41.66%;
}

.col-7-12 {
    width: 58.33%
}



/* Pushing blocks */

.push-2-3, .push-8-12 {
    margin-left: 66.66%;
}

.push-1-2, .push-6-12 {
    margin-left: 50%;
}

.push-1-3, .push-4-12 {
    margin-left: 33.33%;
}

.push-1-4, .push-3-12 {
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.push-1-5 {
    margin-left: 20%;
}

.push-1-6, .push-2-12 {
    margin-left: 16.667%;
}

.push-1-7 {
    margin-left: 14.28%;
}

.push-1-8 {
    margin-left: 12.5%;
}

.push-1-9 {
    margin-left: 11.1%;
}

.push-1-10 {
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.push-1-11 {
    margin-left: 9.09%;
}

.push-1-12 {
    margin-left: 8.33%
}


@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .grid {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 0;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 20px; /* grid-space to left */
        padding-right: 10px; /* grid-space to right: (grid-space-left - column-space) e.g. 20px-10px=10px */
    }

    [class*='col-'] {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 10px; /* column-space */
    }


    /* Mobile Layout */

    [class*='mobile-col-'] {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 10px; /* column-space */
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-1 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .mobile-col-2-3, .mobile-col-8-12 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-2, .mobile-col-6-12 {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-3, .mobile-col-4-12 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-4, .mobile-col-3-12 {
        width: 25%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-5 {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-6, .mobile-col-2-12 {
        width: 16.667%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-7 {
        width: 14.28%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-8 {
        width: 12.5%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-9 {
        width: 11.1%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-10 {
        width: 10%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-11 {
        width: 9.09%;
    }

    .mobile-col-1-12 {
        width: 8.33%
    }

    /* Layout Columns */

    .mobile-col-11-12 {
        width: 91.66%
    }

    .mobile-col-10-12 {
        width: 83.333%;
    }

    .mobile-col-9-12 {
        width: 75%;
    }

    .mobile-col-5-12 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }

    .mobile-col-7-12 {
        width: 58.33%
    }

    .hide-on-mobile {
        display: none !important;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're giving the element a fixed with of 400px. So the browser will render it at 400 regardless of viewport size.

To fix this, I'd recommend using *max-width* instead. Basically, the div will be as wide as possible within the viewport until it reaches 400px - then it will stop.

Also good to note this issue has nothing to do with the grid framework you are using :)

```
#test {
    background-color: green;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Great. This was exactly what I was looking for. If I wanted to override the 20px padding at the smaller viewport size, would I just set the padding to 0 for that div?

Comment: Yes, within the media query for small. That said, the padding is on the column or grid I believe, not the #test element.